# Visual Basic - download from WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, browser

I'm pretty new to visual basic, but have been looking far and wide and have had no luck finding an answer to this anywhere. I've used WebBrowser to navigate to a webpage. On this page there's a link to click which will then download a csv file.

I've got my program to click this link using:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementID").InvokeMember("click")
```

But I'm not sure how to handle the 'file download' dialog box that pops up. One way, I'm thinking, is to use sendkeys to click the 'save' button, but this seems a bit clunky.

I'm wondering if I can use FileDownload somehow to handle this box before it pops up. *(Microsoft's documentation says: "If a file download dialog box can be displayed, this event fires prior to the appearance of the dialog box.")*

Any know if this is possible or do you have any other smart ideas for solving this problem?

Comment: Is the link a static link, or does it call code on the server to launch the download ?

Comment: It's a dynamic link. The button I'm clicking doesn't have a URL that I can just point my code at - it generates the CSV file from running a query on a database.

I can click the link fine with InvokeMember("click"), but I'm trying to handle the 'file download' dialog box.

Is there a way for my code to check if this box has loaded? If my code can be sure that it's there (instead of using a timer or something to wait two seconds for the box to pop up) I could just deal with clicking save by using send keys

Alternatively, it would be amazing to use FileDownload to somehow stop the box appearing